# Flutter keyboard hides textfield in android but working fine in iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

When the text field is focused then the content is scrolled up in iOS but not working in android. Do I need to change the hierarchy of widgets or some configuration needed to change in the AndroidManifest file? I have also tried resizeToAvoidBottomInset and resizeToAvoidBottomPadding properties of Scaffold

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.fill),
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: signUpCardView,
          ),
        ),
        userLogin(bloc),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
Widget get signUpCardView {
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "${AppTranslations.of(context).text("signUp")}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                    fontFamily: customFontFamily,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 20,
                  child: Divider(
                    thickness: 4.0,
                    color: AppColors.BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
          child: nameField(bloc),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
          child: mobileField(bloc),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
          child: emailField(bloc),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
          child: passwordField(bloc),
        ),
        confirmPasswordField(bloc),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: submitButton(bloc),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "${AppTranslations.of(context).text("alreadyHaveAnAccount")}?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                      fontFamily: customFontFamily,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _openSignInScreen();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      " ${AppTranslations.of(context).text("signIn")}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: AppColors.BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                        fontFamily: customFontFamily,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[This is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZHAW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved my issue. It was due to `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in styles.xml.

Comment: It is not working to me after remove <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> also...

Answer (score 1):

To make the screen "resize" ie move to the cursor your android manifest should have this in it:

```
<application
  ...
  <activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: I have already set it as android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". Any other property do I need to set?